# Is a static final char[] thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading

So if I have

```
private static final char[] SOME_CHARS;
```

Is that thread safe? By that I mean if I have multiple threads referring to the chars in that array (but not changing them), will anything go wrong?

e.g.

```
private class someThread extends Thread(){


   public void run(){
     for(int i = 0; i < someIndexInSomeChars;i++){
        System.out.println(SOME_CHARS[i]);
     }
}
```

In other words do I need to put the char[] into some sort of Java collection with thread support?

Comment: No problem there. `String` though, is an assured immutable data type, hence safer. Even changing a char would be fine.

Comment: I've adjusted the title to be closed to the code - `char[]` rather than `Char[]`. I assume that's what you really meant?

Comment: yes- sorry that was a typo - I'll add final to the title too

Comment: If you only read from your static final char array after it has been filled and don't change it anymore, thread safety comes as a bonus. Only if you were to change values in the array from different threads you would have to think about thread safety.  Although immutability does not generally imply thread safety, it helps a lot ;)

Comment: Note that you ''can'' change the contents of a final char[] variable. What you can't change is the reference that that variable holds. i.e. final prohibits "variable = ..." but you could still do "variable[i] = ...".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you don't change them after initialization, it should be fine. (Note that this relies on it being a `static final` variable - the way that classes are initialized will ensure that all threads see the initialized array reference correctly.)

Arrays are safe to read from multiple threads. You could even write from multiple threads if you didn't mind seeing stale results - you wouldn't end up "corrupting" the collection itself. (Unlike many other collections, you can't change the size of an array anyway... there's no state to modify other than the elements themselves.)

Comment: hmm what if I take the char and put it into a String? 
So String = "someStuff " + SOME_CHARS[i]"; and then return the String at some point? I don't forsee this being a problem because the new String should have a new char as opposed to a reference to the old char- is that the case?

Comment: @praks5432: That's fine. It's not clear what you mean by "new char" and "old char" here... don't forget that `char` is a primitive type anyway...

Comment: hmm, so I guess I'm asking this- if I do different things with the same char that I get from the same index in that array, then am I guaranteed that the array won't change?

Comment: @praks5432: Yes. You're just *using* the value - unless you have `SOMECHARS[i] = ...` then you're not changing the value within the array.

Comment: *"You could even write from multiple threads if you didn't mind seeing stale results"* => true as long as assignement for the array's type is atomic (which is the case for anything but doubles and longs).

Comment: @JonSkeet "If you don't change them after initialization, it should be fine."..How can you change them ? Doesn't "final" keyword  prevent us from changing ?

Comment: @JonSkeet "You could even write from multiple threads if you didn't mind seeing stale results - you wouldn't end up "corrupting" the collection itself." . If you are seeing stale values , aren't you corrupting the collection ?

Comment: @Geek: No, the collection is still intact, and you'll see the recent change eventually after an appropriate memory barrier. Compare that with other collections which can be fundamentally broken by inappropriate use.